# AsyncTask doesn't finish the download till the end

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

So I'm building a app which is taking some HTML code from a site and returning some data back, but the problem is that AsyncTask which I'm using onCreate doesn't download the whole HTML code just part of it like it crashes at a certain point I searched quite a bit and tried a lot of solutions but none seems to work.

The only "errors" I'm getting is that there is too much work on the main thread, but how I understand AsyncTask is supposed to be done in the background in another thread.

**Here is the AsyncTask class:**

```
public class SiteInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        URL url;
        String result;
        InputStream inputStream;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;

        try {

            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream = url.openStream()));

            String inputLine;
            final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(inputLine);
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            result = buffer.toString();

            Log.i("download", result);
            inputStream.close();

            return result;
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }

    }
}
```

**Here is the method which clears the HTML code for the info:**

```
    public void getInfo()
    {
    final SiteInfo task= new SiteInfo();
    String result;

    try
    {

        result= task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR,"*random site url*").get();

        String[] temp;
        Pattern urlName= Pattern.compile("<div class=\"image\"><img src=\"\"(,*?)\"/");
        Matcher matcher=urlName.matcher(result);

        for(int i=0; matcher.find(); i++)
        {
            temp=matcher.group(1).split("\" alt=\"");
            imageURL.set(i,temp[i]);
            name.set(i,temp[i+1]);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**And last the call of the method in the onCreate:**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView=findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    startButton=findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    getInfo();

}
```

Comment: [AsyncTask.get()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)  `Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK after adding it just gets stuck, the UI doesn't even load and yet the sites code isn't big

Comment: `buffer.append(inputLine);` To rebuild the lines you should change that to `buffer.append(inputLine + "\n");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the `AsyncTask.get()` instead you should use `new SiteInfo().excute("*random site url*")` to start the AsyncTask and then inside `SiteInfo` overraide the `onPostExecute()` to get your results.

you may want to make another interface to take back results to your activity.

if you have any questions about how to do it let me know

I checked this now and it's working on my phone, don't use Log to see the html response Log can't view long messages, instead, you can you this [Logger](https://github.com/orhanobut/logger)

this was my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DataInterface 
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new SiteInfo(this).execute("https://code.visualstudio.com/");
    Logger.addLogAdapter(new AndroidLogAdapter());

}

@Override
public void returnData(String result) {
    Logger.e(result);
}

public class SiteInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    DataInterface dataInterface;

    SiteInfo(DataInterface dataInterface) {
        super();
        this.dataInterface = dataInterface;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        URL url;
        String result;
        InputStream inputStream;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;

        try {

            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream = url.openStream()));

            String inputLine;
            final StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

            while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(inputLine);
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            result = buffer.toString();

            Log.i("download", result);
            inputStream.close();

            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        dataInterface.returnData(result);
    }
}
}
```

and the interface is

```
public interface DataInterface {
   void returnData(String result);
}
```

Comment: As I replied to the above comment did it and still the download stops like its done even tho it isn't. If you could explain how to make another interface that would be great.

Comment: Thanks this seems to work finally getting normal output. Could you explain why did I need to use Interfaces?

Comment: when your AsyncTask finish and your data is ready  you may want  to update your UI with this data which can't be done inside your AsyncTask, so It's recommended to use Interfaces to bring the result Back to your Activity so you can process them and update your UI

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the `get()` method on an asynctask.

It will freeze your app during the download.

Instead handle the result of doInBackground in onPostExecute().

Comment: I changed the code accordingly and yet the download still "stops", but the thing isn't about the what happens after the download since it doesn't even download it till the end, it always stops at the same line of HTML and runs like its finished downloading.

Comment: `since it doesn't even download it till the end, it always stops at the same line of HTML and runs like its finished downloading.` How did you check that? With logging? Then you should know that not all of a string you want to log will be printed if the string is too long. You could add a log statement to log every line read... and you will see.

Comment: Here is the added code (https://www.pastiebin.com/5e1332b5e928a) in the calling method I just used task.execture("link");

Comment: I checked it with logging on every line and since the program is supposed to extract some data few lines before the stop of the download in an array which is empty since it doesn't find it in the downloaded string.

Comment: Sorry... i do not understand a word of what you are trying to say. I still do not know if all lines are downloaded.

Comment: I did log line by line and no it doesn't download all of it, it always stops at the exact same spot.